# Trezor Firmware update just hangs indefinitely

Tags: trezor

Trezor out of the box - first firmware update with the wallet not even set up and just hangs on "Installing...Please Wait". Read through all of the troubleshooting section on Trezor's website but no help at all. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try it again. If it does not work, contact support and ask for a replacement unit.